# React router Nested routing and data display

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have recently started learning react and react-router-dom. My task is to route the pages dynamically and view data as per the dynamic routes.

so when i routed to this url http://localhost:3000/category
it should display all the categories and when i click each of the category it should render only the child component with the data. Currently it is rendering with the parent component.

Example:
if i route to this url http://localhost:3000/category/nike it should render only the Product component with nike description.
Below is my code. Please help me with your suggestion.

App.js

```
import { Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import Category from './Category';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <Link exact to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/category">Category</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"><Home /></Route>
        <Route path="/category"><Category /></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Category.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, Route, useParams, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import Product from './Product';

export default function Category() {
    const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();
    const productData = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "nike",
          description:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie.",
          status: "Available",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "slippers",
          description:
            "Mauris finibus, massa eu tempor volutpat, magna dolor euismod dolor.",
          status: "Out of Stock",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Adidas",
          description:
            "Maecenas condimentum porttitor auctor. Maecenas viverra fringilla felis, eu pretium.",
          status: "Available",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "puma",
          description:
            "Ut hendrerit venenatis lacus, vel lacinia ipsum fermentum vel. Cras.",
          status: "Out of Stock",
        },
      ];
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {productData.map((product) => {
                    return (
                        <li>
                            <Link to={`${url}/${product.name}`}>{product.name}</Link>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
            <Route path={`${path}/:name`}>
                <Product />
            </Route>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Product.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Product() {
    const {name} = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            {name}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written code in write but that's not the best way to do it , Common and easy way is to create a component for All category view and Particular Category view , another way is to use route `/category` with one component but use query like this `/category?name=nike` , then you can get the query field name value and match , if that field is missing then we can display all the categories

I have written in code sandbox to explain the same , you can refer to that architecture and implement the same

[image: Edit winter-rain-67xqj]

Comment: Thanks @Goutham J.M, this was really helpful and your explanation clarified my doubt. Also thanks for putting it up in CodeSandbox which really explains a lot. Thank you for spending your time in explaining this.

Comment: what if you can have unlimited nested subcategories? What would your Route structure look like? Like this: `category?name1=electronics&name2=computersAndParts&name3=Parts&name4=CPUs` ? So that you can get the hierarchical / deepness level of the category. (Ofc it's better to use category IDs but same sense)